# Question about Nodes in java for my homework

Tags: java

Given main() in the ShoppingList class, define an insertAtEnd() method in the ItemNode class that adds an element to the end of a linked list. DO NOT print the dummy head node.

Ex. if the input is:

4
Kale 
Lettuce 
Carrots 
Peanuts 
where 4 is the number of items to be inserted; Kale, Lettuce, Carrots, Peanuts are the names of the items to be added at the end of the list.

The output is:

Kale 
Lettuce 
Carrots 
Peanuts

CODE:

```
        import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShoppingList {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

      ItemNode headNode;  // Create intNode objects                                                   
      ItemNode currNode;
      ItemNode lastNode;

      String item;
      int i;

      // Front of nodes list                                                                         
      headNode = new ItemNode();
      lastNode = headNode;

      int input = scnr.nextInt();

      for(i = 0; i < input; i++ ){
         item = scnr.next();
         currNode = new ItemNode(item);
         lastNode.insertAtEnd(headNode, currNode);
         lastNode = currNode;
      }

      // Print linked list                                                                           
      currNode = headNode.getNext();
      while (currNode != null) {
         currNode.printNodeData();
         currNode = currNode.getNext();
      }
   }
} 

    public class ItemNode {
   private String item;
   private ItemNode nextNodeRef; // Reference to the next node                                        

   public ItemNode() {
      item = "";
      nextNodeRef = null;
   }

   // Constructor                                                                                     
   public ItemNode(String itemInit) {
      this.item = itemInit;
      this.nextNodeRef = null;
   }

   // Constructor                                                                                     
   public ItemNode(String itemInit, ItemNode nextLoc) {
      this.item = itemInit;
      this.nextNodeRef = nextLoc;
   }

   // Insert node after this node.                                                                   
   public void insertAfter(ItemNode nodeLoc) {
      ItemNode tmpNext;

      tmpNext = this.nextNodeRef;
      this.nextNodeRef = nodeLoc;
      nodeLoc.nextNodeRef = tmpNext;
   }

   // TODO: Define insertAtEnd() method that inserts a node
   //       to the end of the linked list  


   // Get location pointed by nextNodeRef                                                             
   public ItemNode getNext() {
      return this.nextNodeRef;
   }

   public void printNodeData() {
      System.out.println(this.item);
   }
}
```

I'm confused really about adding an element to the end of an linked array, any help would be appreciated

NOTE: ShoppingList.java is read only, I need to edit ItemNode.java

Comment: You have to step through the linked list until you find the node where the next link is null, then point the next link of that node to the node you want to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution, see the comments on the code

```
    public void insertAtTheEnd(String value) {
        ItemNode aux = this.nextNodeRef;
        // Here we check if the list is empty
        if (aux == null) {
            aux = new ItemNode(value);
            return;
        }
        // If the list isn't empty, we iterate over the nodes
        // and we stop before the last one
        while (aux.getNext() != null) {
            aux = aux.getNext();
        }
        // Here we insert at the end
        setNext(aux, value);

    }

public void setNext(ItemNode node, String value) {
        node.nextNodeRef = new ItemNode(value);
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I made a bit of progress. I got the error:                                                                              ShoppingList.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
         lastNode.insertAtEnd(headNode, currNode);
                 ^
  symbol:   method insertAtEnd(ItemNode,ItemNode)
  location: variable lastNode of type ItemNode
1 error                                                                                                                                        This assignment has been  frustrating me but I'm finally making at least some progress

Comment: If you want to have ItemNode and ShoppingList in the same class, only one of them has to be public, adittionally I have renamed the name method in my post